# Change Video in Everyday

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a some videos, that need to be play continuously. But there is a condition, first video should be play upto 24 hours.it means, loop the first video for 24 hours. after that next video. Now the videos are playing continuously. But I Don't know how to set the time for playing videos. Please help me to solve this problem. Thank you.

Here is My code.

```js
var videoSources = ["video/kid.mp4", "video/hands.mp4", "video/video5.mp4", "video/action.mp4"];

var currentIndex = 0;
// listener function changes src
function myNewSrc() {
  var myVideo = document.getElementsByClassName('episodeVideo')[0];
  myVideo.src = videoSources[currentIndex];
  myVideo.load();
}


// add a listener function to the ended event
function myAddListener() {
  var myVideo = document.getElementsByClassName('episodeVideo')[0];
  currentIndex = (currentIndex + 1) % videoSources.length;
  myVideo.src = videoSources[currentIndex];
  myVideo.addEventListener('ended', myNewSrc, false);

}
```

```html
<div class="video-wrapper-main">
  <video onended="myAddListener()" class="episodeVideo" preload="auto" autoplay controls>
             <source src="" type="video/mp4">
      </video>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var videoSources = ["video/kid.mp4", "video/hands.mp4", "video/video5.mp4", "video/action.mp4"];

var startTime = Date.now();

var currentIndex = 0;
// listener function changes src
function myNewSrc() {
  var myVideo = document.getElementsByClassName('episodeVideo')[0];
  var newTime = Date.now();
  var msIn24Hours = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
  var isAfter24Hours = newTime - startTime >= msIn24Hours;
  if(isAfter24Hours) {
    myVideo.src = videoSources[currentIndex];
    startTime = newTime;
  }
  myVideo.load();
}


// add a listener function to the ended event
function myAddListener() {
  var myVideo = document.getElementsByClassName('episodeVideo')[0];
  currentIndex = (currentIndex + 1) % videoSources.length;
  myVideo.src = videoSources[currentIndex];
  myVideo.addEventListener('ended', myNewSrc, false);

}
```

You could then store the start into `localStorage` and use that value.